# Why Push Notification is not working on Android?

Tags: gluon, gluon-desktop

I had push notifications working some time ago, but it is not working anymore.

Is there any issue with `Android 8.0`?

I did not change the `AndroidManifest.xml` since the last working version and I checked up the http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/pushnotes example again.

When sending the message and running the `logcat` I get the following error message:

`No Channel found for pkg=[myPackageName], channelId=null, id=123456, tag=null, opPkg=[myPackageName], callingUid=10298, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10298, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=2 contentView=null vibrate=default sound=null defaults=0x2 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 category=event vis=PUBLIC)`

This one too:

`The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included`

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Update your versions (Down 3.8.5, jfxmobile 1.3.15), something was [changed](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/commits/661b0a28c5c4dbfe3702a4211c164b3684191360) in Push notifications and other services as Android target 26 is required now.

Comment: Thank you @JoséPereda, it worked, but when I close the app, it stops receiving the notifications, do you know why?

Comment: Make sure you have all the required settings for the AndroidManifest for Push Notifications. There is a job for letting them work after you force quit the app.